# How to wait until list is populating in Plugin.Ble?

Tags: c#

Once the device scan is called, the List population is started. How to wait until all data is populated? Here is my code so far:

```cs
public async Task <List<BlueToothDeviceInfo>> GetPairedDevices() {        

    try
    {
        List<BlueToothDeviceInfo> blueToothDevices = new List<BlueToothDeviceInfo>();
        var deviceInfos = new List<BlueToothDeviceInfo>();

        if (bluetoothBLE.State == BluetoothState.On)
        {
            //We have to test if the device is scanning 
            if (!bluetoothBLE.Adapter.IsScanning)
            {
                await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
            }

            adapter.ScanTimeout = ConnectionTimeout;
            adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.Balanced;
            adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
            {
                blueToothDevices.Add(new BlueToothDeviceInfo() { Name = a.Device.Name, HWAddress = a.Device.Id.ToString(),deviceInfoIOS=a.Device });
                //here list added randomly
            };

        }

        return blueToothDevices;
    }            
    catch (Exception ex)
    {           
        HelpClass.LogMessage(0, "BlueToothManager", LogMessageType.ErrorType, ex.StackTrace, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the timeout after you do the scan?  Shouldn't you set the timeout before you run the scan?

Comment: code corrected then also my issue exist

Comment: The await should wait for all the results.  What are you getting as a result.  If you are getting more than one object shouldn't you be using AddRange() instead of Add()?

Comment: Do you mean 'blueToothDevices' is returned when It didn't complete to contain all data?

Comment: bluetoothDevices.add add the devices to the list. But there is not await method in the list.

Comment: await Task.Delay(ConnectionTimeout); this line added at end .I think this is not perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

What about doing like this?

I used `Task.Run()` and `async`

```
public async Task<List<BlueToothDeviceInfo>> GetPairedDevices()
{
    try
    {
        List<BlueToothDeviceInfo> blueToothDevices = new List<BlueToothDeviceInfo>();

        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var deviceInfos = new List<BlueToothDeviceInfo>();

            if (bluetoothBLE.State == BluetoothState.On)
            {

                adapter.ScanTimeout = ConnectionTimeout;
                adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.Balanced;
                adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                {
                    blueToothDevices.Add(new BlueToothDeviceInfo() { Name = a.Device.Name, HWAddress = a.Device.Id.ToString(), deviceInfoIOS = a.Device });
                    //here list added randomly
                };

                //We have to test if the device is scanning 
                if (!bluetoothBLE.Adapter.IsScanning)
                {
                    await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
                }    
            }
        });

        task.Wait();

        return blueToothDevices;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HelpClass.LogMessage(0, "BlueToothManager", LogMessageType.ErrorType, ex.StackTrace, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Thank you. :)